# Unity Play audio clip at random gameobjects positions

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have 8 empty game objects around the camera and I want the same sounds to come from those points in the world.
How can I PlayClipAtPoint correctly to accomplish this.
This script is on my Audio Manager Empty game object. But i want the audio to come from Point1-Point8 transforms position.

```
public class AudioManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform point1;
public Transform point2;
public Transform point3;
public Transform point4;
public Transform point5;
public Transform point6;
public Transform point7;
public Transform point8;
// Use this for initialization
public AudioClip clip1;
public AudioClip clip2;
public AudioClip clip3;
public AudioClip clip4;
public AudioClip clip5;
public AudioClip clip6;
public AudioClip clip7;
public AudioClip clip8;
public AudioClip clip9;
public AudioClip clip10;

public AudioSource audio;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("myFunc", 1.0f, 1.0f);
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void myFunc()
{
    audio.PlayClipAtPoint(clip1,point1.transform.position,0.9f);
}

}
```

Comment: So should myFunc pick a random object *and* a random clip?

Comment: it will at some point i just want the audio to play right now and it does not.

Answer (score 3):

[`PlayClipAtPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html) is a `static` function of the `AudioSource` class. You can't call static functions on instances. You should call it on the type:

```
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip1, point1.transform.position, 0.9f);
```

As a sidenote: I would also recommend you to declare arrays for your `Transforms` and `AudioClips` and populate them in the inspector instead of having a public field for each one. This will make picking random positions and sounds a lot easier (you'd otherwise have to put all of those objects into arrays by hand which is obviously a lot more work and less flexible).

So just replace all of your field declarations with:

```
public Transform[] points;
public AudioClip[] clips;
```

Then just use the index to access them.

Answer (score 0):

your full code will look like this:

```
public class AudioManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
     public Transform[] points;
     public AudioClip[] clips;

     public float volume = 0.9f;

     void Start()
     {
         InvokeRepeating("PlaySoundAtRandomPosition", 1.0f, 1.0f);
     }

     void PlaySoundAtRandomPosition()
     {
         // Take random position
         int rndPosIdx = Random.Range(0, points.Length);
         // Take random clip
         int rndClipIdx = Random.Range(0, clips.Length);
         AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clips[rndClipIdx], points[rndPosIdx].position, volume);
     }
}
```

Don't forget to assign transforms and clips in corresponding arrays from inspector;

Comment: Thanks I got that covered.